# Can I link rvm to brew?

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I couldn't install ruby 2.2.1 using rvm on OS X Yosemite, how ever, it was easy installed using brew.

The question is, how can I let rvm uses ruby 2.2.1 that was installed using brew?

Installing ruby was easy with brew:

```
Apples-iMac:ruby-2.2.1 Apple$ brew install ruby
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ruby-2.2.1.yosemite.bottle.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ruby-2.2.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.1: 1080 files,  21M
```

but in rvm:

```
Apple$ rvm install ruby 2.2.1
ruby-2.2.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.2.1..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.1 - #downloading ruby-2.2.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.1 - #extracting ruby-2.2.1 to /Users/Apple/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.1....
ruby-2.2.1 - #configuring..
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Apple/.rvm/log/1425744075_ruby-2.2.1/configure.log
current path: /Users/Apple/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.1
GEM_HOME=/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/Apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/Apple/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-8/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-8/include/ImageMagick-6/wand:/opt/X11/bin:PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-8/lib/pkgconfig/magick/6.8.9
GEM_PATH=/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5:/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
command(5): ./configure --prefix=/Users/Apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
config.guess already exists
config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.1.0'
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Apple/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

So, is it possible to make the best of both brew and rvm?

Comment: `checking whether the C compiler works... no` -- it seems like you don't have Xcode installed, no?

Comment: I have xCode 5.02 installed

Comment: I found it!
rvm mount /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.1 -n ruby-2.2.1
Apple$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ext-ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

Comment: Try `rvm autolibs brew && rvm install 2.2.1`. The autolibs config option tells rvm to use brew to install dependencies like libyaml.